# How to print the webelement in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to print the element as part of a message when protractor times out waiting for the element.

```
waitForElementDisplayed(webDriverEl, time = timeOut) {
  let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  let isVisible = EC.visibilityOf(webDriverEl);
  browser.wait(isVisible, time, `Timed out waiting for element ${webDriverEl} to be visible`);
}
```

Have not had any luck trying to get the element to print correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not printing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.locator().toString()` to get the locator of a webelement.

```
browser.wait(isVisible, time, "Timed out waiting for element "+element.locator().toString() +" to be visible");
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting "Failed: webElement.locator is not a function"

My code sample:

```
var clickOn = function(webElement){
    return webElement.click().then(()=> {
        console.log("Successfully clicked on the " + webElement.locator().toString());
    });
```