# Unable to print the locator (webelement) in Console Log

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm new to Protractor.

I'm declaring an element as a variable like :

```
txtSearch : element(by.xpath('//input[@type="search"]')),
```

In some point I want to log the locator as :

```
var clickOn = function(webElement)
{
  webElement.click();
  console.log("Successfully clicked on the " + webElement);
};
```

I'm calling this function from Spec file like - `clickOn (txtSearch)`

In `Console.log` I am getting like -  `Successfully clicked on the [object Object]`.

Please find the required details below :

> Node Version: 7.5.0
>
> Protractor Version: 5.1.1
>
> Browser(s): Chrome

Protractor configuration file :

```
exports.config = {
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
          },
   onPrepare: function(){
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
 
       global.isAngularSite = function(flag) {
           browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
       };
       browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
       browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   },
   
  
   seleniumServerJar: '../../protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar',
   chromeDriver: '../../protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.27.exe',
   directConnect: true, 
   framework: 'jasmine2',
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   specs: ['../PoC_Protractor/spec.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000,
        isVerbose: true
    }
```

I tried with `webElement.locator().toString()` but it is throwing-

> Failed: webElement.locator is not a function

Comment: Pls check my answer below .. toString() should work .. Can you update the question with what you tried on that front also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor console log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941739/protractor-console-log)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the webelement in protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267387/how-to-print-the-webelement-in-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

You can always output the locator used using `webElement.locator().toString()`. Check the output for the below code snipper.

Protractor spec:

```
describe('Locator testing by model', function(){
    it('automate user register form', function(){
        browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/registeration/#/login');
        var search = element(by.model('Auth.user.name'))
        console.log(search.locator())
        console.log("Successfully clicked on the " + search.locator().toString());
        console.log(search.locator().toString())
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[14:01:48] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[14:01:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:01:49] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.96.61.119:56341/wd/hub
Started
{ findElementsOverride: [Function], toString: [Function] }
Successfully clicked on the by.model("Auth.user.name")
by.model("Auth.user.name")
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.942 seconds

[14:01:53] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[14:01:53] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[14:01:53] I/launcher - internet explorer #01 passed
```

Comment: Sorry yaar..!! I am still getting the error. here below is my code 
`var type = function(webElement, data){
    webElement.clear();
 console.log("Data " + data +" entered successful on ");
 return webElement.sendKeys(data).then(()=> {
        console.log("Successfully entered the data " + data + " on the  " + webElement.locator().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Hey it seems like you may not be resolving the promise in the correct way, try using -

```
webElement.click().then(function(element){
        console.log(""Successfully clicked on the " + element);
};
```